# How to associate the docker container and its virtual Ethernet interface in host

Tags: networking, docker

Each container is associated to a virtual Ethernet interface on the host named like `veth7K7R1J`. I can find it in `/sys/class/net/veth7K7R1J/statistics`. But I'm wondering how to find this relationship. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given `eth0` inside the container, you need to find the peer_ifindex (which you can do with [`ethtool -S`](https://superuser.com/questions/618968/how-can-i-list-which-virtual-ethernet-pairs-are-running-in-the-current-linux-hos)) and then identify that interface index on the host (with `ip link`). So:

```
$ docker run -it --rm ubuntu:14.04.2 bash
root@07e330775e98:/# apt-get update && apt-get install -y ethtool
[...]
root@07e330775e98:/# ethtool -S eth0
NIC statistics:
     peer_ifindex: 875
```

Then on the host again:

```
$ ip link | grep '^875:'
875: vethdd8c173: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker0 state UP
```